# How do I use || and && in and if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm trying to get the if statement to sense if these two arrays have any parts that are equal.

```
const winningCombos = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
const mySpots = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

function test() {
  winningCombos[0].splice(0, 3, 'testsss')
  //position 0 remove 1
  if (winningCombos[0] || winningCombos[1] || winningCombos[2] === mySpots[0] || mySpots[1] || mySpots[2]) {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'sucess'
  } else {
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = 'fail'
  }
}
```

But I'm also trying to get the if statement to be like

```
if ((winningCombos[0] OR winningCombos[1] OR winningCombos[2]) is equal to(mySpots[0] || mySpots[1] || mySpots[2]) {
    console.log('success');
  };
```

Is there any kind of solution you all can find?

Comment: These are 2-dimensional arrays. You can't use `==` to compare arrays by their contents.

Comment: So `winningCombos[0] == mySpots[0]` can never be true.

Comment: You also have unbalanced parentheses in the second attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate the arrays and compare the items

```js
/**
 * Compares each row of two arrays to determine if they are equal.
 * Rows are considered equal if they have the same length and all corresponding elements are equal.
 * 
 * @param {Array<Array<number>>} a - The first array of rows to compare.
 * @param {Array<Array<number>>} b - The second array of rows to compare.
 * @returns {Array<boolean>} An array of boolean values, each representing whether the corresponding rows in the arrays are equal.
 */
function findSimilarRows(a, b) {
  return a.map((rowA, index) => {
    const rowB = b[index];
    if (!rowB || rowA.length !== rowB.length) {
      return false;
    }

    return rowA.every((element, elementIndex) => element === rowB[elementIndex]);
  });
}

const a = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [5, 9, 0]
];
const b = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 2]
];

console.log(findSimilarRows(a, b));
```

Comment: Using `.includes` would at least avoid hand-coding one of the loops, since they're already arrays; you'd loop over one and `.includes` for the other (only a good idea for smallish arrays, you'd want to switch to another approach if they're large to avoid `O(n²)` runtime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but that isn't what I was trying to do. I was trying to get it to tell me if they were equal or not.